# javax.crypto des sbox

Tags: java, cryptography

Is there anyway i can retrieve the sbox information from the javax.crypto package?

I come across this site that show the sboxes of des alogrithm.
http://www.gymnase-yverdon.vd.ch/branches/mathematique/cryptographie/textes/s_boxes.htm

But i suspect different developers have different implementation on the sbox in another word, it does not mean everyone implement des will use similar sbox value.

Greatly appreciate if anyone can help me with the sbox question.

Comment: If they use different SBoxes, then it isn't [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @sarnold. DES algorithm uses exactly eight sboxes in "Feistel" function in Substitution stage.

However you can not find the sbox imformation in javax.crypto package since it is a specification, not a implementation. you can find sbox imoformation in

`com.sun.crypto.provider` package or

`bouncy castle` implementations or any other provider.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your information :) I been reading through some sbox and seen like sarnold reply is correct. All using the same sbox. At first i though develop will implement their own sbox for security purpose but this is not the case. I guess i use the above link as a reference to sboxes